# MySQL conditionally counting results

Tags: mysql, sum

I have a query which returns the counts of several different types of records but I now need to further qualify the result set.  I am curious if there is an elegant way to combine these statements into a single statement.  Basically if column 2 is true increment ND_true and if column 2 is false increment ND_false instead.

```
sum(if(c.1 = 'ND' and c.2 is true, if(c.2 = 'P', 1, 0), 0)) as 'ND_true'
sum(if(c.1 = 'ND' and c.2 is false, if(c.2 = 'P', 1, 0), 0)) as 'ND_false'
```

Comment: When you say "single statement", do you mean a single Select clause (but multiple columns) or do you mean combine both columns into a single expression?

Answer (score 0):

Erm...

```
select count(*) from `tablename` where [something something something]
```

Seems like a much better alternative to what you're doing. Either that or you're not explaining very clearly what you are doing and what led you to the solution you have.

Answer (score 0):

One alternative:

```
Select ...
    , C.ND_True As ND_True
    , C.ND_False As ND_False
From ...
    Cross Join  (
                Select Sum( Case When C1.P = 1 Then 1 Else 0 End ) As ND_True
                    , Sum( Case When C1.P = 0 Then 1 Else 0 End ) As ND_False
                From SomeTable As C1
                Where C1.1 = 'ND'
                    And C1.P = 'P'
                Union All
                Select Z.Val, Z.Val
                From ( Select 0 As Val ) As Z
                Where Not Exists    (
                                    Select 1
                                    From SomeTable As C2
                                    Where C2.1 = 'ND'
                                        And C2.P = 'P'
                                    )
                ) As C
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query sample although brief is unclear... you are first testing of c1 = 'ND' (string comparison) ANDed with c.2 (implying c.2 is logical), then another if( c.2 = 'P'... )  I'm sure you are abbreviating column names, but this isn't making sense.  Is c.2 a logical field or a string field... one or the other.

```
sum(if(c.1 = 'ND' and c.2 is true, if(c.2 = 'P', 1, 0), 0)) as 'ND_true'
sum(if(c.1 = 'ND' and c.2 is false, if(c.2 = 'P', 1, 0), 0)) as 'ND_false'
```

Here is a simplified version of what I think you are looking for..  In this case, you are concerned with c.1 being "ND", so put that as your WHERE clause to limit what is retrieved from the table.  Then you don't have to re-duplicate it as part of the IF() clause test.  Then, just put in the "other" criteria where I have the c.2 expression...  Since the clause is identical for what is being tested, the 2nd and 3rd columns trigger which column they will be counted in...

```
select
      sum( if( c.2, 1, 0 )) as ND_True,
      sum( if( c.2, 0, 1 )) as ND_False
   from
      yourTable c
   where
      c.1 = 'ND'
```

Ex: Data

```
col1     col2
AX       true
BC       true
ND       true     <-- this row
XY       false
ND       true     <-- this row
ND       false    <-- this row
AX       false
ND       true     <-- this row
```

would result in only the 4 marked rows being queried with a final count of

```
ND_True = 3
ND_False = 1
```